# Objection Relation Mapping with transformed values

Tags: javascript, sql, knex.js, objection.js

Let's say I have two tables :

```
People:

 name : place
----- : ------
ben   : park
phil  : office

Food:

food_place  : vegetable
----------- : ---------
ben@park    : carrots
phil@office : potatoes
```

I'd like to create a Relation Mapping, I tried:

```
  static get relationMappings() {
    const knex = People.knex();
    return {
      food: {
        relation: Model.BelongsToOneRelation,
        modelClass: `${__dirname}/Food`,
        join: {
          from: knex.raw('CONCAT(people.name, "@", people.place)'),
          to: 'food.food_place',
        },
      },
    };
  }
```

That didn't work because objection expected the `from` property to match column name (`Error: People.relationMappings.food: join.from must have format TableName.columnName`).

The idea was to join tables like:

`INNER JOIN Food ON Food.food_place = CONCAT(people.name, "@", people.place)`

**QUESTION** : Is there a was i can do this with relation mappings, or should i use modifiers instead ?

Answer (score 0):

"@" in double quotes will cause error. Use single quotes instead '@'.
The resultant query should look like this :

```
select * from people as people inner JOIN Food ON Food.food_place = CONCAT(people.name, '@', people.place)
```

Replace like this

```
join: {
          from: knex.raw("CONCAT(people.name, '@', people.place)"),
          to: 'food.food_place',
        },
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, but this is not what is causing the error (See updated question)